# A question concerning the directional derivative of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, intuition, curves

As I understand it, intuitively the directional derivative of a function $f$, at some point, describes its rate of change as one moves along a direction, specified by some vector $\mathbf{v}$, away from that point.

With this in mind I am trying to understand the mathematical formalism a bit deeper, but I'm unsure if I am doing so correctly. This is my understanding so far (apologies for any abuse of notation):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be some *smooth* function, and let $c:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be some *smooth* curve in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with coordinates $(x\circ c)(t)\equiv x(t)=(x^{1}(t),\ldots ,x^{n}(t))$.

In a sufficiently small neighbourhood of a point $x(0)=a$ we can describe the curve linearly as $$x(t)=a+t\mathbf{v}$$ where $\mathbf{v}$ is the tangent vector to the curve $x(t)$ at the point $x(0)=a=(a^{1},\ldots ,a^{n})$.

Given this, we can then determine the rate of change in the function $f$ along the direction defined by $\mathbf{v}$ by evaluating $f$ along the line segment of the curve, $x(t)=a+t\mathbf{v}$, such that $f=(f\circ x)(t)=f(x(t))$. In doing so, we can now consider $f$ as a composite function of $t$, such that, upon taking its derivative with respect to $t$ we will determine its rate of change along $\mathbf{v}$. Indeed, $$\frac{df(x(t))}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f(x(t))}{\partial x^{i}}\frac{d x^{i}}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}=\nabla f(a)\cdot\mathbf{v}$$ where $\nabla f=\left(\frac{\partial f(x(t))}{\partial x^{1}},\ldots,\frac{\partial f(x(t))}{\partial x^{n}}\right)$ is the gradient of $f$, and $v^{i}=\frac{d x^{i}}{dt}$ are the components of the tangent vector at the point $x(0)=a$.

Would this be a correct understanding at all?

Comment: You haven't really described the arbitrary curve $c(t)$ but instead replaced it by a linear one.  This is legitimate  but the original curve does not play any role in what you said.

Comment: @MikhailKatz   Yes, I wasn't too sure about this part. In what I've read, the directional derivative seems to always be referred to as "the directional derivative of $f$ along a curve $c(t)$", but I can't see how to arrive at the formula that I've given in my OP without assuming a linear approximation to the curve around a point on the curve. How would one do this?

Comment: I answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really described the arbitrary curve $c(t)$ but instead replaced it by a linear one. This is legitimate but the original curve does not play any role in what you said. Notice that the chain rule formula, as you indicated, contains only the derivatives of the components of $x$ at $t=0$ (you should change $x=a$ to $t=0$).  Therefore the choice of the curve is immaterial, and in fact one can *define* a tangent vector at a point $p$ in terms of an equivalence class of smooth curves through $p$.

Meanwhile the partials of $f$ should be evaluated at $x=a$.

Comment: Have changed $x=a$ to $t=0$ as you said. So is what I have done not wrong, but just misses the point that an equivalence class of curves can be described by the line segment $x(t)=a+t\mathbf{v}$ in the neighbourhood of $x(0)=a$, and not just a single curve, such that they all share the same directional derivative at that point?!

Comment: Exactly, it's not a curve that's relevant but rather an equivalence class of curves.

Comment: So is it correct to start from the parametrisation $x(t)=a+t\mathbf{v}$ (with the caveat that this line segment describes an equivalence class of curves within a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $x(0)=a$) and evaluate the function along this line segment, i.e. $f(x(t))=(f\circ x)(t)$ such that we can determine the derivative of $f$ along $\mathbf{v}$ at $t=0$?

Comment: Yes! Any curve from the equivalence class would do, in particular this one.

Comment: Ah I see, so it's not that we are taking a linear approximation of the curves in the equivalence class, but that there will exist a curve in the equivalence class described by $x(t)=a+t\mathbf{v}$, which we choose because of its simplicity?! In elementary treatments of the directional derivative this point seems to be glossed over. I've read in several introductory texts that the directional derivative of a function along a vector $\mathbf{v}$ is defined as $$\frac{df(a)}{dt}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+t\mathbf{v})-f(a)}{t}$$ ...

Comment: ...but fail to mention about the equivalence class of curves, which suggests the definition only applies to linear line segments.

Comment: You are right, this is a valid criticism of such "introductory texts" though of course it is understandable as the formula one gets is the simplest possible.

Comment: In general then, can one just pick a curve $c(t)$ and evaluate $f$ along this curve (i.e. $f=f(c(t))=(f\circ c)(t)$), then determine the directional derivative of $f$ along this curve at $t=0$, $$\frac{d(f\circ c)(t)}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial (f\circ c)(t)}{\partial x^{i}}\frac{dx^{i}}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}$$ and then recognise that $\frac{dx^{i}}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}$ are the components of the tangent vector to the curve at $t=0$?

Comment: Yes but $c$ should not appear in the partial of $f$.

Comment: Ah, so should it be $\frac{\partial f(x(t))}{\partial x^{i}}$, where $x(t)$ is the coordinate representation of the curve $c(t)$? Also, in the introductory case, would it be better to make some statement, along the lines of: "*although we choose a linear curve to evaluate the function along, note that the derivative of $f$ along $\mathbf{v}$ at the point $x(0)=a$ does not depend on this choice of curve, but only on the vector $\mathbf{v}$*"?!

Comment: No, $t$ plays no role here.  The partials can be computed with no reference to any curve (of course one can choose a curve to compute a partial but that's a different curve).

Comment: Such a statement may be appropriate.  Note that independence of the curve follows from the formula involving the gradient.

Comment: Isn't one evaluating the function along the curve in the first place though in order to determine its rate of change along the curve at a given point, and then evaluating the partial derivatives of $f$ at a particular point $x(0)=a$ (by this I mean $\frac{\partial f(x(t))}{\partial x^{i}}\bigg\vert_{t=0}=\frac{\partial f(x(0))}{\partial x^{i}}=\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x^{i}}$?

Comment: Yes but it's not the same curve.  To find the partial derivative you would evaluate along the $i$-th axis.

Comment: By this do you mean that when taking the partial derivative with respect to the $i$-th coordinate one considers the values of the function at $(a^{1},\ldots ,a^{i},\ldots a^{n})$ and $(a^{1},\ldots ,a^{i}+tv^{i},\ldots a^{n})$, i.e. $f(a^{1},\ldots ,a^{i},\ldots a^{n})$ and $f(a^{1},\ldots ,a^{i}+tv^{i},\ldots a^{n})$, such that $$\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x^{i}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a^{1},\ldots ,a^{i}+tv^{i},\ldots a^{n})-f(a^{1},\ldots ,a^{i},\ldots a^{n})}{t}$$

Comment: Yes, exactly.  This has nothing to do with either the curve $c$ or the vector $v$.

Comment: But doesn't it depend on the $i$-th component, $v^{i}$ of the vector?

Comment: NO! You are not adding $tv^i$ to the $i$-th coordinate, but rather $t$.

Comment: But I thought that one evaluates the function along the line segment $x(t)=a+t\mathbf{v}$? Is it simply that when taking the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the $i$-th coordinate, we are considering two nearby points $(a^{1},\ldots , a^{i},\ldots ,x^{n})$ and $(a^{1},\ldots , a^{i}+h,\ldots ,x^{n})$, such that $$\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x^{i}}=\lim_{h\rightarrow}\frac{f(a^{1},\ldots , a^{i}+h,\ldots ,x^{n})-(a^{1},\ldots , a^{i},\ldots ,x^{n})}{h}$$ ...

Comment: ...which doesn't depend on the line segment $x(t)=a+t\mathbf{v}$, since we are considering the partial derivative of $f$ at a particular point $a$ which corresponds to $x(0)=a$?!

Comment: The point of the formula is to express the directional derivative in terms of the gradient and the components of $v$.  The calculation of the gradient has no relation to the curve $c$ at all! You only need the point where the derivatives are calculated, not any infinitesimal information.

Comment: Ah ok, so is the point that we can simply take the partial derivatives of $f=f(x)$ with respect to the coordinates $x^{i}$ without evaluating it on the curve since we are evaluating the derivative at a particular point $x=x(0)=a$ which doesn't depend on the behaviour of the curve in the neighbourhood of $x=a$ at all?!

Comment: Exactly, you got it.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for all your help! Would you say that I understand the concept (and mathematical formalism) of the directional derivative now (from our discussion)?

Comment: I think so.  I would just add that in general to understand a concept in mathematics, it is helpful to look at the simplest meaningful case first, to make sure you understand that.  It is possible that had you worked out first the case of a two-variable function $f(x,y)$ you may have reached the conclusion faster (there is less formalism to get lost in).

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the advice. Would one consider a parametrisation such as $x(t)=x_{0}+at$, $y(t)=y_{0}+bt$. Then, $$\frac{df(x,y)}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}=\frac{\partial f(x_{0},y_{0})}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f(x_{0},y_{0})}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{\partial f(x_{0},y_{0})}{\partial x}a+\frac{\partial f(x_{0},y_{0})}{\partial y}b=\left(\frac{\partial f(x_{0},y_{0})}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f(x_{0},y_{0})}{\partial y}\right)\cdot\left(a,b\right)$$ Clearly $(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt})=(a,b)$ are the components of the vector tangent to the line segment at $t=0$...

Comment: ... and so the directional derivative of $f$ along the vector $(a,b)$ is independent of the line segment that we chose, and only depends on the point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ and the vector $(a,b)$.

Comment: That's fine....

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for all of your help. Much appreciated!